# Why can't I use the array's append() in Swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, struct, append

I'm getting a: `Cannot invoke 'append' with an argument list of type '([Book])'` It works find if I use the `+=` but I don't understand why `append()` won't work.

```
struct Book
{
    var title:String
    var pageCount:Int
}

class Library
{
    var onShelfBooks:[Book] = []
    var onLoanBooks:[Book] = []
    var books:[Book]
    {
        get
        {
            return onShelfBooks + onLoanBooks
        }

        set(newBook)
        {
            onShelfBooks.append(newBook)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
struct Book
{
    var title:String
    var pageCount:Int
}

class Library
{
    var onShelfBooks:[Book] = []
    var onLoanBooks:[Book] = []
    var books:[Book]
    {
        get
        {
            return onShelfBooks + onLoanBooks
        }

        set(newBook)
        {
            onShelfBooks.append(newBook[0])
        }
    }
}

var myLibrary = Library()

var newBook = Book(title: "Swift Development with Cocoa", pageCount: 453)

myLibrary.books = [newBook]

myLibrary.books
```

Answer (score 2):

Append only allows you to add one object at a time while += allows you to combine an array of objects with another object. When you call append on the setter you are trying to add an array of book objects, or [Book] instead of just a single book object.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to add [newBook] with append, you can use : of
**1-** onShelfBooks.**append**(**contentsOf**: newBook)
"contentOf" is type of **Sequence**.
otherwise use of:
**2-** onShelfBooks **+=** newBook